# SQL - Products with No Sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to list all the Products that have had no sales. I'm really close but I'm trying to use the NOT EXISTS statement to display all the ProductID's that are in the Product table, but not in the Orderline table; and hence have no sales. My code is as follows;

```
SELECT product.productid
FROM product
JOIN orderline ON product.productid = orderline.productid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (

SELECT orderline.productid
FROM orderline
)
ORDER BY productid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the Subselect by simply doing a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT product.productid
FROM product
LEFT JOIN orderline USING (productid)
WHERE orderline.productid IS NULL
ORDER BY product.productid
```

`LEFT JOIN` will list *all* rows in `product` even when there is no JOIN partner in `orderline`. In that case all columns in `orderline` have `NULL` values. These are the rows you want in the result.

Comment: Perfect this seems more logical than the NOT EXISTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you must use `not exists`, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM orderline o
        WHERE p.productid = o.productid
        )
ORDER BY p.productid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the products that does not exists in orderline table you can simply use LEFT join with `WHERE orderline.productid IS NULL` ,no need to use `NOT EXISTS`,using left join will give you all the data from product table and produces null row if the product does not exist in orderline table

```
SELECT p.productid
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN orderline o ON p.productid = o.productid
WHERE o.productid IS NULL
ORDER BY p.productid
```

Comment: "no need to use NOT EXISTS" - why not? It reads better: where not exists (any related sale)

Comment: @meze in my answer i have define a little working of left join that when there is no association of product in orderline table then above query will provide null row joined with product row so i have used `o.productid IS NULL` which means that product is not in orderline table there is no sense to use again not exists part

Comment: When there are products with many orderlines, your answer might get slower than a `where not exists`. WHERE NOT EXISTS can jump off after the first found order, LEFT JOIN where is null is at least harder to optimize and often measurable slower (when there are many orderlines). Even stronger, `NOT EXISTS` is much easier to read from index orderline.product_id, without touching the table at all.

Comment: @flaschenpost i agree with you by reading the explanation [*here*](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24888) i will take care of this in my future answers thanks

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thanks for the link! It very much depends on the situation, but as far as I understand `orderline` it could be a great number for some products. When the "not exists" table is a small table with extra data for some rows, it should be no great deal.

Comment: I think, in most situations, both versions will translate into the same execution path

Comment: @Strawberry I have anecdotal evidence in postgresql but that is about it. Think of it this way, if the optimizer was always able to determine the best execution path then all equivalent relational algebra would get executed through the same, ideal, path. I know that is not the case, but sql is a declarative language, you aren't telling the RDBMS what to do, you're declaring what you would like back. Thus the goal shouldn't be to write the most performant query but instead to write the most readable. After all, the engine is going to execute your query however it sees best.